# Power BI switching between datasources

Tags: powerbi

I am new to using Power BI gateways. I have created a dashboard using Power BI Desktop connecting to the Test server. Now I have been asked to switch to Production but they wont give me access to the Production. Instead they have setup a data source using Manage Gateways in PBI Service and they are asking me to consume it in my reports. I am so confused if it is actually possible to switch my reports to Production without having access to it. I believe we cannot link PBI Desktop with the DS setup in the Gateway connections directly.

I tried parameterizing database connection so that they can switch to Live and publish it. But they raised a question if they change the password one day and there are many reports published, will they have to go through each of these reports and update with the new password.
Can anyone please provide me a solution for this?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: its on-prem sql database

Comment: What do you mean by Test and Production server? Are they Power BI service or You are talking about Database server?

Comment: thank you for your response. It's DB server i meant by. Sorry for not making it clear. I created the dashboard using test db server. Now i am asked to switch it to prod db server. But they wont give me access to prod db server. Is there any way to switch the report to prod without having access to it.

Comment: Do you have all information to connect production database? like server name, user id and pasword?

Comment: no they wont give me the userid and pwd

Comment: I created a parameterized connection so that they can switch the report from their side using the parameters and publish it, But they asked if one day they change the datasource password wont they have to go through all these reports and update it. Thanks a lot R_R for your support

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this approach, but you can try and check this works for you or not.

1. In your local Power BI file, In **Data Source Settings** provide the **Production server** name.
2. Give a dummy **User ID** and **Password**
3. Now publish the report to the **Power BI Service**
4. Ask your admin now to add appropriate Gateway to the data source. While adding gateway to the data source, the admin should asked for database **Credentials** and after providing information, it should work.

As I said this is not tested here, I can just hope for the best :)

Comment: Thanks again R_R. I tried it. But it wont publish with a dummy user id and password. It prompts to enter a valid username and password. When trying to publish I get "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided" message.

Comment: Then just ask your admin to provide a read only user details to you. Other wise give them the report and ask them to set credentials and publish.

Comment: Thank you R_R!  You are so helpful. 